# R barplot, bar size = x axis * y axis?

Tags: r, bar-chart

[image: sample barplot with different size of bar]

In R,

is it possible to get the barplot (or whatever the name of this type plot is), that the size of each bar area = value of x axis * value of y axis.

Thanks.

**==============================**

**updated:**

Actually I am trying to make a chart to show the performance (speed+accuracy) of the tools I was testing. There are 7 small plot in a panel. That gives some sort of overview, of course there are more detailed plots just for speed and accuracy for each tool.

In the plot, some symbols (15 symbols in total) overlapped each other, so it could be hard for the reader to find out which are the symbols behind the others.

And that was the reason I am seeking other ways of doing this.

[image: xy scatter plot of performance]

A also did a bubble plot for the performance (green: accuracy, red: speed), this is only a initial version of it, but still, it doesn't look OK. 
[image: bubble plot for performance]

Comment: Have a look at the `symbols` function. It is quite difficult to work with, but will probably do the job. I am sure there is a nicer way to do it with ggplot too.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_rect.html) can be usefull?

Comment: thanks for above 2 replies, I will have a look. I am trying not to use ggplot, as I have a lot plots have been done in basic R package, ggplot produces plot with different look, the color, style etc.

Comment: You can produce a `ggplot` with a basic theme....

Comment: You could do this the brute force way using `rect()`. However, I'd suggest you think long and hard about what information you want to convey and whether this is the best way to do so. I don't see a good interpretation of "CPU Time times Accuracy", which your squares visualize. Maybe you just need a scatterplot of CPU Time against Accuracy?

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with Stephen K.  What is the message you're trying to send to the reader?  For example: is a large box better than a small one? (presumably not, since most of us want to minimize CPU **and** maximize accuracy).

Comment: using cpu time doesn't make more sense, which refers to 'the larger, the better'. I have calculated the 'speed', so by using the values of speed + accuracy, larger box better than the small one.  I will update the post, to explain my problem clearly.